# How to join two entity objects together?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, join

I took a look around for an answer to this and what I have found is similar to what I am doing but not getting it quite right. I can join two entities when they are lists but not when they are singular objects. I am not sure if this makes sense

Here I have two entity objects

```
Location location = VIPEF.Locations
    .Where(w => w.LocationID == id).FirstOrDefault<Location>();
Contact contact = VIPEF.Contacts
    .Where(w => w.ContactID == location.ContactID).FirstOrDefault<Contact>();
```

But when I go to write a query:

```
var query = from a in location
            join b in contact on a <-- Thats where I get a problem
```

once I go to join the two I can't get the ID from location, and the only option i get is `a.equals` and not `a.LocationID` as I think I should be getting.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Why do you want to join 2 entity objects together? This is not a query, it's just a projection to another class, for example `var x = new Thing { LocID = location.LocationID, LocName = location.Name, ContactName = contact.Name .... }`

Comment: @DavidG, I am joining two objects together so I can return a single object with the joned data. I don't use LINQ very often, I typically would use storedprocedures. But looking at your example, I understand what to do now and what I was doing wrong. If you wanna post that as an answer with a more indepth explanation then I would be more than happy to mark it as an answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need Linq to join two objects together, you just need to compose a new object. It's fairly simple using [object initialiser syntax](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384062.aspx):

```
var thing = new Thing //<-- Your class that has the combined properties you need
{
    LocationID = location.LocationID, 
    LocationName = location.Name,
    ContactName = contact.Name,
    ContactAddress = contact.Address,
    //etc...
};
```

Alternatively, you can do this all in one go rather than 2 queries and then the composition:

```
var things = from l in VIPEF.Locations
             join c in VIPEF.Contacts on l.ContactID equals c.ContactID
             where l.LocationID == id
             select new Thing
             {
                 LocationID = location.LocationID, 
                 LocationName = location.Name,
                 ContactName = contact.Name,
                 ContactAddress = contact.Address,
                 //etc...
             };
```

This will give you an `IEnumerable<Thing>` to play with though it may only have a single entry.